# Почему не появляется "System.InvalidOperationException"?

Tags: c#, winforms

Недавно начал изучать `Thread` и `Invoke` и столкнулся с проблемой.
Почему следующий код выполняется без `Exception`:

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(DoStuff1);
    thread.Name = "new thread";
    thread.Start();
}

private void DoStuff1()
{
    this.label1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => label1.Text = "info from new thread"));
    button1.BackColor = Color.Red;
    DoStuff2();
}

private void DoStuff2()
{
    label1.Text = "info from new thread";
}
```

Интересует почему тело метода `DoStuff2` выполняется, ведь мы все же обращаемся к контролу который был создан в другом потоке.
И, кстати, если в `DoStuff2` сам текст немного изменить, например на `info from new thread2`, то уже будет `Exception`. Это какая-то особенность языка, он проверяет что сам текст не меняется и не вызывает присваивание текста? И почему также выполняется без Exception `button1.BackColor = Color.Red`, здесь мы ведь тоже обращаемся к контролу?

Comment: Возможно это оптимизация компилятора, вы ничего не меняете своим оператором, соответственно компилятор его опускает

Comment: У контролов есть свойство `InvokeRequired`, которое показывает, нужно ли обращаться к нему через `Invoke` или можно напрямую. Обращение к `Text` зависит от него. А вот `BackColor` ведёт себя действительно странно. Но, возможно, это просто случайность. А может быть, оно действительно не нуждается в инвоке. Это нужно разбираться в исходниках.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov оно аффектит вызов `OnPaint` и вызывает инвалидацию визуального дерева отрисовки, следовательно оно не может не нуждаться в инвоке.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Свойства некоторых контролов не защищены от изменений из потоков, только и всего. Возможно это сделано в целях оптимизации, потому что на проверку контекста синхронизации все равно уходило бы какое-то время, возможно по каким-то другим причинам.

То есть обращение таким образом к `Label` допустимо, но целостность данных в свойстве `Text` - ваша ответственность, так как вероятные проблемы при конкурентном редактировании свойства этого контрола никуда не делись. .NET вам просто разрешает это сделать.

По сути исключения при обращении к контролам из стороннего потока берутся не из ниоткуда, а только там, где разработчики .NET эту проверку встроили, чтобы обезопасить нас от самых популярных ошибок при работе в условиях многопоточности.

В WPF есть пример, где подобное исключение возникает при использовании обычной коллекции - `ObservableCollection`, при использовании ее в контексте синхронизации UI. При попытке модифицировать коллекцию из стороннего потока выскочит `NotSupportedException`, причина - ровно та же, что и у вас в вопросе. А это ведь вообще не контрол.

Так что избавляйтесь от шаблона, что это некая особенность контролов - не давать себя менять из потоков, это просто такое решение разработчиков .NET, где добавить проверку, а где - нет.